# Managing messages processed by a dynamic send port

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, send-port

We are building a distribution system where an incomming message is routed to a destination based on content of the message. This pattern in biztalk is relatively straightforward. In our solution, messages come in, are stored in a repository, and also distributed to the appropriate 3rd party.

We have several functional requirements of an administrative web application that would be used by an operational support person.

- No BizTalk knownedge required to perform administrative duties
- Ability to report on message counts of queued messages by destination
- Ability to cancel queued messages
- Ability to resend message from the repository
- Ability to search for message in repository, and see its status within the send port (suspended, retry, etc)

Essentially we need the ability to manage the messages through a web application, not using any biztalk tools, and only for this specific biztalk solution.  Any suggestions for implementation suggestions, patterns or examples that do something similar?

Comment: Are you trying to use Biztalk as the repository for the messages?

Comment: No.  Ideally the repository would be seperate.  I live to leave the biztalk databases alone as much as possible.

Comment: Seems like this could be done using sql server for a repository, some web services to manipulate it, and some web pages to present a user interface. Biztalk can deliver the messages for you as you have deduced.

Comment: I've figured that much.  But I'm sure the web app would need to be able to manage messages that are currently being processed by biztalk (suspended, processing, queued, etc).  Not sure how to best go about that

Answer (score 1):

You can query the biztalk database directly to gain information about the state of biztalk (like what the management console does). A lot of details are [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7253.biztalk-server-2010-database-biztalkdtadb.aspx)